# Export and update table using SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a question that I hope has a simple answer. I wrote a little automated and scheduled project in SSIS which queries a table, saves the table data as an excel file and updates the queried table with a flag indicating the row has been processed.

Very simple.

Well the requirement is to do this in SSRS, not SSIS. Is that even possible? 
If it is I'm not seeing it. I haven't previously used SSRS, so I'm not even sure what SSRS is capable of, or where to begin looking. I've searched for tutorials and everything, and I haven't found what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not** meant as a full answer but is too long for a comment....

Giving a full answer would require much more detail from you but...

Basically when you create a dataset for your report to output, it's just a bunch of T-SQL that eventually returns some data. You can do what you like with it before or after.

So in your case you might do something like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = @myParameter

UPDATE myTable SET myOtherColumn = 'somevalue' WHERE myColumn = @myParameter
```

SSRS Will See the result of this query as the result of the `SELECT` which you can then use in a tablix on your report.

Thats the report side covered but then you'll need to export to Excel. If you need to automate this then you can either create a subscription or you can call a URL (see here for details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/export-a-report-using-url-access)

Hopefully that will give you enough to get started.